# Ionic - View Leave Events Never Called

Tags: ionic-framework

After updating an existing Ionic project from 1.13-beta to 1.14-beta I've experienced some behaviour I can't explain. When changing from one viewstate to another, the old view doesn't leave the page. Upon logging both angular ui router events and Ionic navigation events I've noticed Ionic's Exit Events aren't fired:

```
$ionicView.leave
$ionicView.beforeLeave
$ionicView.afterLeave
```

Documentation: (http://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-the-changes/)

Has anyone else experienced similar behaviour? If so, have you found any way to resolve this?

Events Fired:

```
$stateChangeStart: App.LoadApp.Input -> App.Main.QrToken
$viewContentLoading: Main
$viewContentLoading: QrToken
$stateChangeSuccess: App.LoadApp.Input -> App.Main.QrToken
$ionicView.beforeEnter
$ionicView.afterEnter
$ionicView.enter
```

I can load in the QrToken view if I Don't nest it inside Main, so I believe the problem lie there. Can anyone take a look at my Main Template and help me find a solution.

```
<div ng-controller="fbMenuController">
    <ion-side-menus>

        <!-- Left menu -->
        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
                <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content scroll="true">
                <div ng-repeat="Group in fb.Model.MenuGroups">
                    <ion-item class="item-divider">{{Group.Name}}</ion-item>
                    <!-- href="#/Main/{{Page.Name}}" -->
                    <a ng-repeat="Page in Group.Items" nav-transition="android" nav-direction="swap" class="item" ng-click="fb.SelectPage(Page.State)">
                        {{ Page.Name }}
                    </a>
                </div>

            </ion-content>

        </ion-side-menu>

        <!-- Center content -->
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" ng-show="fb.Model.ShowHeader">
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button class="button-icon icon ion-navicon" ng-click="fb.ToggleLeftMenu()"></button>
                </div>
                <h1 class="title">{{ fb.Model.ActivePage.Name }}</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>

            <ion-content scroll="true">
                <ion-nav-view name="Main">

                </ion-nav-view>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu-content>

    </ion-side-menus>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at my solution listed below => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938408/ionic-view-leave-events-never-called/42905435#42905435

Answer (score 2):

If your view is wrapped in a tab using `<ion-tab>`, you need to register for `$ionicNavView`-Events:

```
 $scope.$on("$ionicNavView.leave")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an open issue https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2869 and probably occurs when view-cache="false".

On my case `$ionicView.leave` worked in nested views but not when moving between tabs nor did `$ionicParentView.leave` so I came around it with another solution.

**Solution:**
On MAIN controller I added:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
     if (fromState.name === 'name-of-leaving-state') {

      //your code here, similar behavior with .$on('$ionicView.leave') 

     }
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem the other day. I was listening for the event on my child controllers. When I moved the listener to the parent, it worked. I wasn't quite sure why, but now I think I know why. It's because of the way Ionic caches the views. Specifically this line from the docs:

> If a view leaves but is cached, then this event will not fire again on
>   a subsequent viewing.

It's likely that your views were cached before you added the listener and the leave event never fired. But since your parent is... well... the parent, its leave event is triggered any time you leave any of its children. I haven't officially tested this, it's just a hunch. To test, try telling ionic to not cache the view by adding *cache-view="false"* to your ion-view declaration.

See docs [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/).

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The 'Main' state was defined without the attribute

```
abstract: true
```

this worked in Ionic 1.13-beta but Aparently breaks in Ionic 1.14-beta. Didn't find this change in any of the migration posts on either Ionic, AngularJS or Angular-ui-router, so I don't know why this solved it. If anyone can elaborate more on the behavior in this situation, I'd be grateful but for now I have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, however i wanted to add that on Ionic v1.3.4 (the last version) the `$ionicView.beforeEnter` && `$ionicView.afterEnter` all work. I mention this because others have commented that v1.3.x was having issues with controller views for `.beforeEnter and .afterEnter`.  But I don’t ever recall having issues on any version of 1.3.x.

That being said, I came to this thread because I am updating an older ionic v1 app and ran into a problem where the `$ionicView.beforeEnter` was not firing and I could not figure out why. It turns out the template that goes with that controller was missing closing HTML tags on a few `<i class="icon>` elements…I didn’t add the closing `</i>`

Thus, apparently, certain elements missing a closing tag was preventing the controller `$ionicView.beforeEnter/afterEnter` functions from firing. Don't know if its all tags or specific tags but I can say I had NEVER seen that before so it took me a while to figure out the issue was in my template and not in my controller.

For what its worth, hope my discovery helps those in the future.