# In Ionic, how to ask users to confirm before leaving a page? If No is chosen, how to cancel the leaving behavior?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've written the codes in the `$ionicView.beforeLeave` event handler. But it seems not effective. Because when this event happens, the page has been shifted, so it's too late to popup the confirming dialog. And I don't know how to prevent the default behavior of this event. I've tried `event.preventDefault()`, but it's useless. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

```js
$rootScope.$on("$ionicView.beforeLeave", function (event, view) {
  $ionicPopup.confirm({
    title: "Confirm",
    template: "Data has been modified. Are you sure to discard the changes and leave anyway?"
  }).then(function (res) {
    res || event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29690353/6554634 refer this link and check for other answers to the same question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default ui-router then an option would be to subscibe on the `$stateChangeStart` event.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    // Navigation will be prevented
    if (!some_check_variable) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

You can read more on the ui-router documentation here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-Router/wiki

check the stateChangeStart section